# Bootstrap, making responsive changes to layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, responsive-design

I'm using a fluid Twitter Bootstrap layout for my design and am about to make it responsive. Consider a grid such as this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span8"></div>    
</div>
```

What is the best way to hide span4 and let span8 take up the entire width, to be used when the screen gets smaller?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a media query with whatever min/max width set `.span4` to `display: none;`

Then, add `.span8` to the rule for `.span12` for everything below whatever width you hide `.span4` as all that work is already done for you by bootstrap, so no need to duplicate. It will look something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 320px){
    .span12,
    .span8 {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

(That last bit of code is just an example, but there will be something like it in bootstraps scaffolding.)

Hope that helps :)

**EDIT:**

This could work, I tested it using dev tools on the bootstrap site and it seemed to work. Again, in a media query:

```
@media (min-width: 320px){

    #special .span4 {
        display: none;
    }

    #special .span8 {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would rather  use an Id instead of applying display:none on .span4, but good answer. +1

Comment: span12/span8 are used throughout the design, in sidebars/subgrids and so on. So I'd need to apply an ID to that column and use media queries to say "now be span8", "now be span12". Only in Bootstrap, the grid classes are created dynamically like ~"span@{index}" { stuff } for various indexes (using a recursive construction) and so they don't actually exist and I can't use LESS to include them in my ID definition. That means I have to duplicate code and essentially recreate the grid, I'm not too happy about it. But your solution is a working one though, thank you.

Comment: I've updated my solution, that should be a bit better, and hopefully no duplication.

Answer (score 24):

With bootstrap 2.0.2 and up you can:

Change the html to:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 hidden-phone hidden-tablet"></div>
    <div class="span8 span12-tablet"></div>    
</div>
```

(I interpreted 'smaller' with tablet and phone sizes, use your own definitions for other sizes)

.hidden-phone and .hidden-tablet hide the span4 for smaller screens.

To reclaim that space and re-span the span8, add this to your css:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  .span12-tablet {
    width: 91.48936170212765% !important;
    *width: 91.43617021276594% !important;
  }
}
```

If you happen to be using less you can use bootstrap's grid mixins:

```
.span12-tablet {
    @media (max-width: 979px) {
        #grid > .fluid > .span(12) !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also suggest how to change what is displayed? By using `hidden-phone` I can hide that div no doubt but how can I instead substitute it with something else?

Comment: @Legend could you not just have a `visible-desktop span4` under it?

Comment: @Gert-Jan van de Streek how did you come up with those % values?

Comment: I really like the name you chose, "span12-tablet." Fits in very well with other bootstrap classes like hidden-tablet, visible-tablet etc.

Comment: How would .span12-tablet class look for sass ?

Answer (score 6):

**If using bootstrap 2.2.1 you can:**

Change the html to:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 hidden-phone hidden-tablet"></div>
    <div class="span8"></div>    
</div>
```

Now add this to your css overrides:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) 
{
    [class*="span"],
    .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

**This will also work for any other span widths you have specified in your html.**

the effect of these changes makes all span widths 100% causing the iPad to always use 1 column fluid mode in portrait mode.

Comment: Hey, Really like this answer but what if you have 3 spans and you just want it when one span to consume the rest of the space?

Answer (score 3):

This would be the best option to keep it dynamic. In my example I have width set to 6 columns next to fluidGridColumnWidth

```
[class*="span"]  {
    width: 100%;

    .row-fluid {
        [class*="span"] {
            width: (@fluidGridColumnWidth * 6) + (@fluidGridGutterWidth * (6 - 1)) - (.5 / @gridRowWidth * 100 * 1%);

            float: left;
            margin-left: @fluidGridGutterWidth;

            &:first-child {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write Like this

in phone device this div will hide`<div class="span4 hidden-phone"></div>`

and this div will show  `<div class="span8 visible-phone"></div>`

**Update**

Previous Answer for Bootstrap 2.3

Now bootstrap 3 come in market..

so i update my answer for new user → bootstrap3

in phone device this div will hide`<div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs"></div>`

and this div will show  `<div class="col-xs-4 visible-xs"></div>`

Comment: you don't need any @media tag

Comment: There is hidden-lg, hidden-md, hidden-sm, hidden-sx now. Also if you hide span4, and span8 is a block unless it is floating. In this it should be a float div. So this solution will not work in this way.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: Use the 2nd code snippet**

Bootstrap is a mobile first framework so I'll explain from the smallest screen-size up. The layout is always 12 columns wide regardless of breakpoints/screen-size.

Starting from the smallest breakpoint (xs - extra small), the `span4` is hidden and the `span8` takes all of the width (all 12 columns)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="span8 col-xs-12"></div>    
</div>
```

We are not quite done yet as we haven't defined behavior when the next breakpoint up is hit (sm/small/screen width is over 767px), so we'll make `span4` take a third of the width (12 columns/3 = 4 columns) and the `span8` will take the rest of the width (12-4= 8 columns)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 hidden-xs col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="span8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8"></div>    
</div>
```

The above assumes you wanted the change to happen on the change between the xs - sm breakpoints.

**Further reading:**

If you wanted the change between sm-md (md = medium) then I might use the [visible-md](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) class which will show the `span4` on breakpoints medium and up (>992px)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 visible-md col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="span8 col-xs-12 col-md-8"></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a small variation of that.

Add `stack-tablet` class to a `row-fluid` to make the spans stack on tablet width, not only on phone width (bootstrap default):

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .row-fluid.stack-tablet [class*="span"] {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Can be used together with the display- and hidden- classes.

Answer (score 0):

just:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4 hidden-desktop"></div>
   <div class="span8"></div>    
</div>
```