# How to display different layout on different screen size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My example use bootstrap, but the answer can use other css framework or only css

In this example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">C</div>
</div>
```

If width of screen larger than 991px

It will display

```
[A][B][C]
```

otherwise it will display

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
```

But I don't want to display different style only, I also want to display different layout

For example:

Larger than 991px

```
[A][B][C]
```

smaller

```
[B]
[A]
[C]
```

Another example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">C</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">D</div>
</div>
```

Larger

```
[A][B]
[C][D]


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">C</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">D</div>
</div>
```

Smaller

```
[D][B]
[C][A]


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">D</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">C</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
</div>
```

How can I use css to do that?

Comment: Try [this JS plugin](http://responsejs.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap, making responsive changes to layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037517/bootstrap-making-responsive-changes-to-layout)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can rearrange the columns in bootstrap.
Have a look here : ["Reorder CSS Cloumns"](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap)

Comment: It can change order but cannot move to other node

Comment: You can try play with the flexbox properties or have a look at this framework it might be helpful https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid